# Square root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra

A polynomial $F=X^2+Y^2$ in an algebraically closed field $k$ is reducible (because $k$ is algebraically closed), can I say that $F=X^2+Y^2=(X+Y)(X-Y)$? I'm asking that because the book I'm using says that $F=X^2+Y^2=(X-\gamma Y)(X+\gamma Y)$, where $\gamma$ is the square root of unity. Which one is correct? is there  such  a $\gamma$? I need a hand here.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your signs are off. $(X+Y)(X-Y) = X^2 - Y^2$ holds for any field, not just ones that are algebraically closed. Note the minus. Now, if the field is algebraically closed, then you have a solution to the equation $x^2 = -1$, which we normally call $i$. With this in the field, now you can factor $X^2 + Y^2 = (X+iY)(X-iY)$.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

$(X+Y)(X-Y)=X^2-Y^2$ so you can't write $F=(X+Y)(X-Y)$.
$(X-\gamma Y)(X+\gamma Y)= X^2-\gamma^2Y^2$.So, if $\gamma$ is square root of $-1$ then $X^2+Y^2$ can be factorized. Such a $\gamma$ exists as $k$ is algebraically closed.

However, it's not clear from the question whether you are factorizing $X^2+Y^2$ or $X^2-Y^2$- are there typos in the question above?

Comment: yes, there is a typo, I'm going to edit it, thanks.